# Heroku will not render 'paginate.render' correctly

Tags: ruby, heroku, pagination, kaminari

I'm using kaminari, everything works fine locally.  On heroku, any code written inside the standard kaminari `paginator.render` block is not getting rendered.

consider

```
<%= paginator.render do %>
  <h1> this is the paginator</h1>
  <nav class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <%= first_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
      <%= prev_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
      <% each_page do |page| %>
        <% if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window? %>
          <%= page_tag page %>
        <% elsif !page.was_truncated? %>
          <%= gap_tag %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= next_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
      <%= last_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

I added the `<h1>this is the paginator</h1>` to tinker with what is happening.  My logs look clean, there is not issue.  am I missing something really obvious here?  I've looked at the kaminari docs and given things are working locally, I'm not entirely sure what to look at on heroku, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the same version of the gem locally as on heroku?

Comment: @Adrian it would appear as though i was, http://cl.ly/image/2C3H0S093u0E  http://cl.ly/image/2f2E2F2w3x0E

Answer (score 0):

## snap, this hurted, my collection didn't have enough objects in it, therefore, kaminari had nothing to paginate.  #usererror